# how git/svn handle project.pbxproj conflict?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When A and B change the project's structure at the same time,the project.pbxproj will conclict in git/svn. this file can't be treated as text file, how could I solve this conflict?
Now, I have to override one's project.pbxproj and manually apply another's structure.
Any sugguest? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *can* be treated as a text file.  It's ugly, but you can usually figure out what the various lines of text in there are doing, and merge with some elbow grease.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the project file in your favorite text editor (even in Xcode).  The project file structure isn't *totally* transparent, but it's actually quite human-editable, and in all but the most exceptional circumstances, the conflicts are generally very easy to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git, just add a .gitattributes file and add one line：

```
*.pbxproj binary
```

This line will tell Git to treat all pbxproj files as binary data.